# In java, how to call the values from input class?

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to bring a variable from one method into another for use, especially that from input class. For example, this test program doesn't work. How would I make it work?

**So here's my main class(Main.java):**

```
class Main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        Input f = new Input();
        f.inputting(num1, num2, num3);
   }
}
```

**and my input class(Input.java):**

```
import java.io.*;

class Input
{
     void inputting(int number1, int number2, int number3)
   {
    Console d = System.console();

    String a = d.readLine("Enter 1st number:");
    String b = d.readLine("Enter 2nd number:");
    String c = d.readLine("Enter 3rd number:");

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(b);
    int num3 = Integer.parseInt(c);

    Sort e = new Sort();
    e.sorting(num1, num2, num3);
   }
 }
```

**and my sort class(Sort.java):**

```
class Sort
{
  void sorting(int number1, int number2, int number3)
  { 
  if (number1 > number2) {
    int temp = number1;
    number1 = number2;
    number2 = temp;
  }

  if (number2 > number3) {
    int temp = number2;
    number2 = number3;
    number3 = temp;
  }

  if (number1 > number2) {
    int temp = number1;
    number1 = number2;
    number2 = temp;
  }

   System.out.println("\nThe sorted numbers in ascending order are "
    + number1 + " " + number2 + " " + number3);
  }

  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass three parameters to `inputting`? They are not being used at all.

Comment: you are ommiting the package information.  Are they in the same package? What error are you getting?  Also this code will not compile because `num1` etc in main are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing arguments into `inputting` with `f.inputting(num1, num2, num3);`, but you never declared `num1`, `num2`, or `num3` in main.

If your intent is to do the user input from within the `inputting` method, you don't need the parameters for the `inputting` method, so you could do `f.inputting();` in main and change the method declaration to `void inputting()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be

```
class Main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        int num1=1;
        int num2=2;
        int num1=3;
        Input f = new Input();
        f.inputting(num1, num2, num3);
   }
}
```

Also, you should use ELSE IF!, if not, it could enters the 3 ifs...

```
if (number1 > number2) {
    int temp = number1;
    number1 = number2;
    number2 = temp;
  }

  else if (number2 > number3) {
    int temp = number2;
    number2 = number3;
    number3 = temp;
  }

  else if (number1 > number2) {
    int temp = number1;
    number1 = number2;
    number2 = temp;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set up a global variable that sub classes or other classes use or you can call the variable from the class like so:

Class Main

```
class Main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        Static int number1;
        Static int number2;
        Static int number3;

        Input f = new Input();
        f.inputting(number1, number2, number3);
  }
}
```

Class Input

```
int Main.number1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
int Main.number2 = Integer.parseInt(b);
int Main.number3 = Integer.parseInt(c);
```